# how to JUnit test ContentResolver.notifyChange

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, android-testing

I'm writing tests for a `ContentProvider`, in `insert` I'm notifying about changes with `getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(mUri, null);`

my tests class extends `ProviderTestCase2`. I created the following mock ContentObserver class:

```
private class ContentObserverMock extends ContentObserver {
    public boolean changed = false;

    public ContentObserverMock(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        changed = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and this is the test case:

```
public void testInsertNotifyContentChanges() {
    ContentResolver resolver = mContext.getContentResolver();
    ContentObserverMock co = new ContentObserverMock(null);

    resolver.registerContentObserver(CONTENT_URI, true, co);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_TAG_ID, 1);
    values.put(COLUMN_TAG_CONTENT, "TEST");

    resolver.insert(CONTENT_URI, values);
    assertTrue(co.changed);
}
```

seems like `onChange` is never called, I also tried `ContentObserverMock co = new ContentObserverMock(new Handler());` with the same result.

what am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ProviderTestCase2` uses `MockContentResolver`. Checking source code, it's `notifyChange` method does nothing.

```
@Override
public void notifyChange(Uri uri, ContentObserver observer, boolean syncToNetwork) {
}
```

Your scenerio can't be tested with `ProviderTestCase2`. Take a look at [ProviderTestCase3](http://source-android.frandroid.com/packages/apps/Browser/tests/src/com/android/browser/tests/utils/), but it uses android private packages.

**Edit:** I have made a library consisting of new `ProviderTestCase3` class as a replacement for `ProviderTestCase2` that keeps calls to `ContentResolver.notifyChanged` internal to observers registered with `ProviderTestCase3.registerContentObserver`. You can use it to test notify changes.
https://github.com/biegleux/TestsUtils

Usage:

```
public void testInsertNotifyContentChanges() {
    ContentObserverMock observer = new ContentObserverMock(new Handler()); 
    registerContentObserver(CONTENT_URI, true, observer);
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_TAG_ID, 1);
    values.put(COLUMN_TAG_CONTENT, "TEST");
    getMockContentResolver().insert(CONTENT_URI, values);
    assertTrue(observer.mChanged);
}
```

Don't forget to `extends ProviderTestCase3<YourProvider>`.

Comment: can I test it with `InstrumentationTestCase2` ?

Comment: No, it won't help either, as it doesn't expose required functionality. Here you can see what you can test using Content Provider Testing API http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/contentprovider_testing.html#WhatToTest. I would rather say notifyChange() is not a logic that you own and have to test. You have to implement functionality similar to ProviderTestCase3, but as stated it uses some private packages so you may hit some troubles trying to rewrite that class.

Comment: what I actually want to test is that the `ContentProvider` is calling `notifyChange`

Comment: is it possible to check that the `ContentProvider` is calling `notifyChange` without additional libraries ?

Comment: those are just three classes, you can simply copy them to your src folder, this way you don't need to link it as a library

Answer (score 4):

I use [Robolectric](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/) to unittest as much as I can  without running the emulator. I verified calling an update on the contentResolver like this:

```
ShadowContentResolver contentResolver = Robolectric.shadowOf(
    service.getContentResolver());
final List<NotifiedUri> notifiedUris = contentResolver.getNotifiedUris();
assertThat(notifiedUris.get(0).uri, is(uriToVerify));
```